# Laplace of InverseLaplace not equal to self

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I define a function

```
A[f_] := f - LaplaceTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t], t, s]
```

and then evaluate

```
Simplify[A[Exp[x/Sqrt[1/s]]], x > 0]
```

I should get a zero but I see
[image]

Comment: `InverseLaplaceTransform` returns a conditional expression valid only for `x<0`. I get `undefined` for `x>0` . What version of mathematica?

Answer (score 2):

```
a[f_] := f - LaplaceTransform[InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t], t, s];
a[Exp[x/Sqrt[1/s]]];
Assuming[x < 0 && s > 0, Simplify[%]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]